# Distance measurements unit in 2d image points (python)

Tags: python, numpy, distance, pixel, units-of-measurement

I used Python + Numpy to calculate the distance perpendicular to a point to a line defined by two points in a two-dimensional image (the coordinates of each point are the location of the point in the two-dimensional matrix of pixels.)

```py
    p1, p2, p3 # as the points    
    
    # calculating the distance of p3 to the line constructed out of the p1 and p2
    # distance formula using the cross product approach
    d = numpy.linalg.norm(np.cross(p2-p1, p1-p3))/numpy.linalg.norm(p2-p1)
```

The question is :

**What is the output measurement unit of distances that is calculated in this way?**

**Is the distance `d` calculated in 'pixel'?**

If the answer is yes,
**How can I convert it to the millimeter and other measurement units?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when i worked on dicom images. If you are working on dicom, you can find a dicom tag named **PixelSpacing**. This tag is defined as two numbers like (0.02, 0.08); which the first number indicates the the row spacing in mm (vertical distance between two adjacent centers) and the second number indicates the column spacing in mm (horizontal distance between two adjacent centers.)

Answer (score 0):

If the points come from an actual image, the distance is in "pixels" (In actuality, the distance is in whatever arbitrary unit you assign to values of your `p1, p2, p3` - math doesn't care, for Python it's just a number) - but not the ones on your screen. If you have an 2x2 image and tell it to show up fullscreen, you will obviously get 1 of those virtual pixels take thousands of actual pixels on your display.
If you take 4k image and try to display on a 640x480 monitor, you will obviously have to  combine few virtual pixels to determine what color you need to show.
In the same vein, you cannot convert that to other measurement units without setting some arbitrary conversion dependant on your exact setup.

Comment: thanks for the answer. that was really helpful.
but when I'm working with an image consisting of 512*512 pixels with predefined intensity levels and calculating the distance, doesn't a fixed window for converting the pixel unit to the millimeter for example?

Comment: I think you need to know the DPI of your image (maybe using pillow?). then you can do the calculation:

1 inch = 25.4 mm,
dpi = Eg. 96 px/inch,

1 pixel = 25.4 / 96